# Using .value in shared setting definition in SBT / Sane way to organize settings based on Scala version

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to provide a multiple settings based on Scala binary version.
Those settings would be shared between several projects.

Something like:

```
lazy val akaneSettings = Def.settings(
  organization := "ws.kotonoha",
  moduleName := "akane",
  crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.12", "2.12.4"),
  scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
  version := "0.2-SNAPSHOT",
  javacOptions ++= Seq("-encoding", "utf8"),
  scalacOptions ++= Seq(
    "-feature",
    "-deprecation"
  ),
  scalaBinaryVersion.value match {
      case "2.11" =>
        Def.settings(
          scalacOptions ++= Seq(
            "-Ybackend:GenBCode",
            "-Yopt:l:classpath",
            "-Yopt-warnings",
            "-target:jvm-1.8"
          ),
          libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-java8-compat_2.11" % "0.8.0")
        )
      case "2.12" =>
        Def.settings(
          scalacOptions ++= Seq(
            "-opt:l:classpath"
          )
        )    
      case _ => throw new Exception("Not supported yet")
    }
  }
)
```

Unfortunately, the pattern match on .value does not work: it requires that I use it within a macro context.

Of course I can do the branching logic for each individual setting and use := / ++=, but that will leave a mess.
Is there a way to sanely organize groups of settings based on Scala version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your conditional checks to *inside* the settings definitions, and not generate multiple settings *from outside*.

SBT's syntax might give the impression that you're updating values in a mutable fashion, such as by using the `:=` operator, but you're not. Every single setting transformation is stored to be composed and applied later. At the point where `akaneSettings` is defined the value of `scalaBinaryVersion` is not known (and may actually be different depending on the context being evaluated).

Your example should look somewhat like:

```
// No need to use Def.Setting in recent SBT versions
lazy val akaneSettings = Seq(
  organization := "ws.kotonoha",
  // ...,
  scalacOptions ++= {
    scalaBinaryVersion.value match {
      case "2.11" =>
        Seq("-some-2.11-setting")
      case "2.12" =>
        Seq("-some-2.12-setting")
      case _ =>
        sys.error("Only Scala 2.11 and 2.12 are supported")
     }
  },
  libraryDependencies ++= {
    scalaBinaryVersion.value match {
      case "2.11" =>
        Seq("org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-java8-compat_2.11" % "0.8.0")
      case "2.12" =>
        Seq.empty
      case _ =>
        sys.error("Only Scala 2.11 and 2.12 are supported")
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create functions to generate your settings. For example:

```
def akaneSettings(scalaBinaryVersion: String) = Def.settings(
  ...
  scalaBinaryVersion match {
    ...
  }
)
```

... and then using it as `akaneSettings(scalaBinaryVersion.value)`.

Comment: I believe you still need to use .value for extracting scalaBinaryVersion in a macro context.

Comment: But you would do so in a place where `.value` is valid.

Comment: For example: `lazy val proj1 = (project in file(".")).settings(akaneSettings(scalaBinaryVersion.value))`

Comment: Unfortunately `project.settings()` is not a macro context as well.